# How to connect to the MySQL database in XAMPP from localhost?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I currently have a nodeJS script to connect to the MySQL instance running on XAMPP:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'testdb'
});
dbconn.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('Database connection error', err);
            response = "Database connection error";
        } else{
            console.log('Database connection Successful');  
        }
    });
```

I already have all the XAMPP instances running (`MySQL`, `ProFTPD`, and `Apache`) and enabled `localhost:8080 -> 80 (Over SSH)`.

When I run the script above using `node App.js` I am getting the error:

> Database connection error { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

I have already updated my `my.cnf` file to add: `bind-address=0.0.0.0` as seen below:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Any suggestions? I have been beating my head over this for the past few hours and can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Firewall, perhaps?

Comment: @PaulT. This is on my personal Mac computer. I don't think I have a firewall setup. Or is there some other place I have to change the configuration for a firewall?

Comment: Unfortunately, for Mac, I'm not sure. If you could check to see if the firewall is enabled, then temporarily disable, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @PaulT. Ok just checked in my system preferences, the firewall is turned off on my Mac. Sigh...

Comment: After the bind-address change, did you restart MySQL?

Comment: Yes I restarted it on XAMPP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192461/discussion-between-paul-t-and-capturedtree).